# How to edit Resource Permissions on Para Web Console

Tags: json, angular, api, para

I'm following this guide https://erudika.com/blog/2016/06/09/Building-the-stack-from-scratch-with-Angular-2/  to make an angular recipe project and I did as it says, but when I reach step 1 I have to edit some permissions, this is the code I need to put in there but I don't have the edit option, any idea?

```
{
  "*": {
    "recipes": ["*", "?"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Para web console was configured to show apps in "read-only" mode. This has been fixed now. Just hard refresh https://console.paraio.org and the edit button should be visible.